# Make Column fill the available height using Foundation Flex Grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to code a page layout that roughly looks like [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/ierik/pen/ZpaZKz), I have the `main` container that needs to fill the entire browser screen (`100% height`), and two child `div` elements of 12 columns.

The first column has a fixed height, and I need the second one to fill the rest of the vertical space available in the container. However when I set the `height` of the second column to `100%`, instead taking the remaining height of the container, it just gets `100%` of the height of the parent container and ends up with the same height as the parent container. Is there a way to make the second column simply fill the remaining vertical space left?

EDIT: The height of the first column is not actually fixed, it may vary.

Answer (score 1):

If the parent container is `height: 100%`, and there is a child element with `height: 100px`...

When you give the other child `height: 100%`, it will overflow the container because it's sibling has already consumed 100px.

In other words:

```
100% + 100px > 100%
```

Instead of this:

```
.box-two {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Try this:

```
.box-two {
  background: red;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

Comment: All right, that does work, but actually the height of the first column could vary, so I can't tell it's height in all situations.

Comment: That does work with a simple flex container, but I want to be able to use Foundation's responsive features, and it's Flex Grid works in a different way, I don't think the rows would even work properly with a `flex direction` of `column` in Foundation. How can that be done using the Foundation Flex Grid?

Comment: I've never used Foundation Flex Grid. I tried to assist with standard flex properties and concepts. Good luck!